# Does Roam-bot supports "Sign in with Google"?

Tags: roamresearch, roam-bot

I'm using RoamResearch with Sign In With Google feature, how do I use it with Roam-bot?

Answer (score 0):

Sign in with google is not supported in Roam-bot. You will have to go to your RoamResearch settings and switch to a standard login/password connection in order to use them in Roam-bot.